# Transfer file to Python Pickle File

Tags: python, file, pickle

I am finding out about the Standard OTA package.
I found that it have some the Python Pickle File format which using for upgrading.
I tried writing an app in Android which can simulate this process.
But my problem is I dont know how can transfer from a file to Python Pickle File.
(Example: .apk ==> .apk.p)
How can I do it?

Comment: I want to simulate the process with the platform layer.
The first time, I think that I only need the transfer using GZipStream. 
But it is the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

A python pickle file is an object, or objects from the python language that have been dumped as bytestream into a file. I am not sure that is what you want, I think you should do a bit more research on what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to turn a pickle an .apk, then try find the information of the .apk file. Then out all that info into a dictionary then pickle it like this.

```
import pickle
def name();
 pickle.dump(open(Name_Dictonary,wb))
```

or at least that might work